# Can't establish connection between controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm new to Rails and I'm stuck at something really silly. I was trying to make an app where users can post pinterest-like pins, so I went with user has_many: pins and pin belongs_to: user. Here's the codes from a few files just to give you an idea of what state I'm in right now:

app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :pins
end
```

app/models/pin.rb

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

pins_controller.rb

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :find_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @pins = Pin.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @pin = current_user.pins.build
  end

  def create
    @pin = current_user.pins.build(pin_params)

    if @pin.save
      redirect_to @pin, notice: "Successfully created new Pin"
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @pin.update(pin_params)
      redirect_to @pin, notice: "Pin was successfully updated!"
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @pin.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def error
  end


  private

  def pin_params
    params.require(:pin).permit(:title, :description)
  end

  def find_pin
    @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

/views/pins/show.html.haml

```
%h1= @pin.title
%p= @pin.description
%p
%hr
%strong Submitted by
= @pin.user.email
```

Here, in the last line of show.html.haml, I want the @pin.user.email to be a link so that

1. the profile of the user (the one who submitted the article) can be accessed when clicked on it.
2. the profile of the user should list all of the articles submitted by him/her.

These are the two things that I'm trying to accomplish but don't know the code I should use for it. I don't have a users_controller. I did have one but I deleted it after it started messing with devise's routes. All answers are welcome, thanks in advance!

Comment: `I don't have a users_controller` -- Step one: create a `UsersController`.

Comment: If you're getting conflicts with third party tools such as `Devise` (although I doubt it will be an issue just yet...), you can namespace your controller actions in `config/routes.rb` by placing your routes in a `scope` block.

Comment: Okay I just created a `UsersController` and edited routes.rb but I still don't know what the path should be after `= link_to @pin.user.email`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Of All Create User Controller.
Redirect Show page line to user show action
Then you perform what you want.

For Ex.

link_to "User Profile", user_path(@pin.user.id)

users_controller.rb

class UsersController < ApplicationController

def show
   @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
   @pins = @user.pins
 end
end

/views/users/show.html.haml
User @user and @pins to Display What you want.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to define your show method

```
 def show
    @pin        
 end
```